# Directly run second form from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to directly run a second form as a debugging option?
I know you can change the form in Program.cs, but that can get annoying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, would you please rephrase ?

Comment: You could have a Console running at the same time for debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to open a new 'debug' form:

```
    Form debugForm;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    #if DEBUG
            debugForm = new Form();
            debugForm.Show();
    #endif
```

If you just want text output then use the Console by changing your Output Type in Project => Properties  to Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to show the second form directly.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                    frm.FormClosing += (s, o) => this.Show();
                }));
                return;
            }

        });
    }
```